# alternative to motherboard serial for unique identifier?

Tags: windows, identity-management

I need to use an ID that is unique for idenrifing a PC, even after reloading the OS. After doing some research on finding the best unique identifier, I decided on motherboard serial number. But on my machine it returns null for the serial number. Is there another unique identifier I can use besides the MAC address?

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop> wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
Manufacturer  Product  SerialNumber  Version
LENOVO        LENOVO   NONE          NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest having a look at the Code Project article of
[Generating Unique Key (Finger Print) for a Computer for Licensing Purposes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer).

You will find there the code in C# that was in turn found by the author and which
he himself uses for his licensing needs.

The author lists these very sensible  points :

> - Generate a key from only the Motherboard, Processor and BIOS since the user normally doesn't change these parts.
> - Don't use MAC ID, Graphics Card ID AND Disk ID since it's very common to change these devices.
> - It takes significant time to get IDs of devices. So make the finger print generating function static and save it in a static variable so
>     that it generates the key only once in the whole application.

Regarding the motherboard serial number returned as null,
this is a different matter that merits further study.
It might be that the code included in the article will work better,
or perhaps the CPU and disk might do where the motherboard serial is
inaccessible.

I remark that you don't need a function that uses data that is universally
available, since different hardware might not have all the serials
you want. All you need is concatenate data from a number of sources,
skipping the ones that are not available, just being reasonably sure that the total
resulting fingerprint string from the ones that are available will be pretty unique.

Comment: Sorry, your answer appeared while I was writing and checking mine. Maybe you know if the UUID is a good solution.

Comment: @AFH: UUID is usually pretty unique, unless self-generated, but UUID of what?

Comment: It is included in the system information, along with a _system_ serial number (which is not defined on one of my laptops).

Comment: @AFH: I don't know, but it might be an alternative where it can be found. The poster doesn't need a serial function that uses universally available serials, just a function that will fingerprint a given computer.

Comment: The value is returned with `wmic csproduct get uuid`, according to [this link](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-find-out-bios-motherboard-and-cpu-info-from-command-line). If it's generally implemented, then it's a more straight-forward solution than creating and saving a composite identifier.

Comment: @AFH: This seems to be that of the BIOS, and I wouldn't wager of it being universally available or not changing after a BIOS update or identifying anything other than this BIOS version. I think the poster should construct the fingerprint by concatenating values from a list, just skipping the ones that don't work.

Comment: Why not just create a UUID of your own?

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard serial number is a good identifier, but [not all manufacturers encode it in firmware](https://forums.evga.com/FindPost/2642814).

The MAC address is OK, but which one? A laptop may be connected by Ethernet, on-board WiFi, or USB WiFi for better performance.

There is a system UUID, which is by definition unique, but I cannot be sure if it is universally implemented.